# Recover using recovery partition of Windows

Tags: windows-8

I have an HP laptop that had a genuine Windows 8 on it. It started giving issues and so I decided to reinstall the OS after wiping everything. Before wiping the data, I took a backup of the Windows key using this method - https://www.howtogeek.com/660517/how-to-find-your-windows-10-product-key-using-the-command-prompt/.

I reinstalled Windows 8 from an ISO I downloaded from the Microsoft website. When I tried to install it, the OS did not accept the old key. I tried with various versions of Windows 8 such as Single Language, Home, Pro and even 8.1 but still the key did not get accepted.

I later found that I have a recovery partition created by the manufacturer, however, I do not know how to use it. Whenever I try to boot into Recovery Mode, the partition does not show up at all when I select the option to reinstall from recovery drive

How do I get my preinstalled version of Windows 8? All I have now is a Windows Recovery partition which I don't know how to use and a Windows key which I backed up before wiping everything. I do not have any of the CD's that came with the laptop.

Please help.

Comment: Manufacturer recovery isn't always the windows recovery option. Also having a recovery option may just be windows' powertools partition, aka the menu you get when you boot into the special menu from UEFI with options for a command prompt, and boot repair. They don't give a full OS reinstall. If it is the Windows recovery, then you should search for "reset my pc" in the start menu to access that form of recovery.

Comment: Did you attempt to install Windows 8 or Windows 8.1?  Windows 8.1 cannot be installed with a Windows 8 key, but can be activated, I did exactly that for my own machine.  What you have at this point on the drive cannot be used to reinstall (whatever version of Windows came with your machine) due to your previous actions.  Given you attempted to use multiple versions of Windows 8.x it’s unclear what you originally had installed.  The article you linked to has some major issues, you probably didn’t write down, the correct key.  However, it’s not required, as that problem can be worked around

Comment: @LPChip yeah I think that's what it is.

Comment: @Ramhound yeah. I just did not notice which version of Windows 8 I had. Also I suspect the key I have now is not the correct one as you say. Is there anyway I can find which version of Windows is the key intended for ? How do you say I can work around this problem ?

Comment: Where did you get the key from in the first place?

Comment: F11 at boot should get you the HP recovery function, that is if the partition is not damaged.

Comment: @Moab I got the key from running the command in cmd. I am able to go into the Windows recovery mode, but when I try to restore from recovery partition, I'm not able to select the correct format.

Comment: Couldn't find a sticker on the laptop. Guess I just lost a genuine version of Windows.

Comment: Try to install Windows 10, it may still accept your Windows 8 serial. And it's much better.

Comment: Tried that too. But the key doesn’t work.

Comment: @Moab - Windows 8+ COA stickers DO NOT have the license printed on them.  Windows 8 licenses are stored in the ACPI table, the Windows Installation Environment (Windows 8+) automatically pulls the license key during the installation process.

Comment: @v1shnu - Then you are attempting to install Windows 10 with a generic VLK key, and not your actual license key.  Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 keys absolutely can activate Windows 10.  If you are unable to activate Windows 10 then you have installed the incorrect edition.  What will be on the COA sticker is which edition of Windows 8 that came with the system.  If you determine what version you had installed, we can help you, without that information that will be extremely difficult.